# Problem regarding Pappus Chain

Tags: geometry, soft-question

So, I got this interesting problem from [Dheeraj Dhobley's blog on Medium](https://dheerajdhobley.medium.com/?p=fbc87f2781b9). Here's the problem:

[image]

The answer to this problem is available on the site I've provided above. According to that site, the answer is:

> $$r(n) = \frac{4}{4n^2 + 12n + 17}\tag{1}$$

I also found there's a general formula that, possibly, able to solve this problem i.e. when I looked-up the Pappus Chain. I found the formula from [WolframMathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappusChain.html). I'm absolutely sure that the problem seems to be similar. For convenience, look at this figure below:

[image]

It says there that to find the radius of $n^{\text{th}}$-of the circle in the chain, if $r\equiv \frac{AB}{AC}$ then

$$r_n = \frac{(1-r)r}{2\left(n^2 (1-r)^2 + r\right)}$$

From the first figure (the original problem), it's clear that $r=1/2$ and when I plugged it into the formula above, I got:

$$r_n = \frac{1}{2n^2 + 4}$$

Which is different from $(1)$ How so? Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Please check how '$n^{\text{th}}$ circle' is defined in the two situations.

Comment: @Flagged great. I see the difference. I thought I could solve the problem easily by the known formula of Pappus Chain turned out I was wrong.